# Retrieving Cookie values from different domain

Tags: search, cookies

I have a site for example mysite.com which store a cookie when user enter etc.

But my search page has a different subdomain/domain search.mysite.com.

How do I retrieve the cookie from mysite.com? when i try to retrieve the cookie using the google search appliance . it gets me the cookie for  search.mysite.com. I need the cookie values from mysite.com.

Is there any way retrieve the cookie from mysite.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should set the domain of the cookie to be ".mysite.com".  All sub-domains will then have access.  The syntax for the Set-Cookie header is as follows:

```
Set-Cookie: name=newvalue; expires=date; path=/; domain=.mysite.com
```

Comment: the cookie is set somewhere else. and the google search appliacne is on using something like mysite.search.com and when I try to get the cookie from mysite.com it doesnt seem to get it.

Is it possible to retrieve cookie from a different domain? 
How do i do it?

thanks

Comment: You can't: it would be a giant security hole if `mysite.host.com` could grab any cookie it wanted from `yoursite.host.com`.